# Safely remove directory with unknown contents

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link, rm, hard-link

I have a directory /usr/local/foo, which I need to remove.
This is going to be part of a script, which needs to be run as root.
I'm mainly worried that the directory, which contains things that users can edit, could contain something that causes a simple "rm -rf /usr/local/foo" to accidentally delete other things.
For example, if they managed to symlink foo to point to /dev or something and rm followed it.

I would like the directory **gone**, along with whatever is in it. This includes user files, symlinks, and everything else. *However,* I would like it to not delete /dev if some malicious user has symlinked foo to /dev.

System: Ubuntu and FreeBSD and OSX

Comment: Installing and running Midnight Commander for visual inspection with then removal would be safer.

Comment: Do not worry. `rm` will always delete the actual contents of the folder only. It will only remove a symlink itself, never the contents that the symlink points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command I was looking for was

```
rm -fr --one-filesystem foo
```

rm does not follow symlinks, and will just unlink the file.

Answer (score 3):

If `/usr/local/foo` might contain user files, or your files, modified by the user, here's what to do:

Provide your script with a list of the filenames you want to delete (`/usr/local/foo/{file1,old.txt}` and a method of checking for user modifications. Checksums (`man md5sum shasum`) or file modification dates (`man stat`) are but two of the many methods you could use. Use `bash`'s `[[ -f $filename ]]` test to ensure the "file" you're deleting is a file, not a link, subdirectory or whatever. (`man bash`)

Delete (`man rm`) the files on your list that pass the "unmodified" test.

Then, take advantage of `rmdir`'s refusal to delete non-empty directories (`man rmdir`) with

```
rmdir /usr/local/foo
```

Ignore the error message and error status. If `/usr/local/foo` was empty, it's gone. If it had remaining files, it's not gone.

Comment: Note that this is not the answer to the question I asked. I did my best to specify that I don't care about what is in the folder, if a user put something there I want to erase it anyway. What I wanted to know was how to make rm not follow symlinks, hard links, or anything else.